# What's the best way to support Android 2.x tablets in my app?

Tags: android, user-interface, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

I'm developing an Android app that absolutely needs to support Android 2.1+ devices, including tablets and phones.

The tricky part is I want to be able to provide roughly the same user experience on Android 2.x tablets as on bone fide Honeycomb tablets. I'm planning on using the Compatibility package so that Fragment support is always available, but...

The problem I've got at the moment is I've bought a Hannstab for testing, and discovered that it reports to apps that it has a "large" screen, despite actually being 10.1 inches. This would technically make it "xlarge", but of course that category was not included in Android 2.2 (which it runs), hence it's "large". I originally intended to just use resource qualifiers and treat all xlarge devices as tablets, and everything else as phones but now I realise I can't do that.

Would it be so bad to treat all xlarge **and** large screened devices as tablets? This would include Dell Streaks and other 5 to 7 inch screen devices as I understand it.

Is there a better alternative? I haven't really got my head around fragments properly yet so a fragments-based solution might be obvious to someone who has.

I've noticed that typically, apps I install on my Hannspad use their normal phone UI, with the exception of Evernote which uses a specific tablet interface - I wish I knew how they'd done that.

The new "Smallest Width" resource qualifier introduced in Android 3.2 would solve this problem by doing away with the generalised screen size buckets altogether. Presumably I could copy this approach by writing code to work out the screen width in dp and then adding fragments to the activity as appropriate. Is that wise? I'd rather avoid that kind of work if it's going to be a pain.

Cheers

Comment: @C Norris your comment should go as an update to your original question (otherwise it's overlooked). You can use Edit link under the question to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be so bad to treat all xlarge and large screened devices as tablets?

If your question really is "is it OK to use the same layouts, etc. for `-large` and `-xlarge` devices", that certainly can work. It's certainly where I would start.

Bear in mind that device manufacturers really are the ones who determine what is `-large` or not. It would not surprise me to find some manufacturers creating 5" devices to categorize them as `-normal`, because they feel that `-normal` apps tend to work better on their devices than do `-large` apps.

> I've noticed that typically, apps I install on my Hannspad use their normal phone UI, with the exception of Evernote which uses a specific tablet interface - I wish I knew how they'd done that.

Probably using `-large`/`-xlarge` resources. I don't know if they are using fragments or not.

In terms of screen sizes, fragments really are for cases where the `-large`/`-xlarge` UIs are basically a bunch of `-small`/`-normal` sized UIs snapped together like LEGO(R) blocks. In Evernote's case, their `-large`/`-xlarge` UI does not fit that pattern, so they may or may not have used fragments.

Fragments offer some other advantages for memory management and configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation), so you might consider using fragments even if you are not sharing fragments between major groups of screen sizes.

> Is that wise?

If possible, I would hold off on making that decision until Ice Cream Sandwich ships and we start seeing how some of this stuff will play out on smaller-screen devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll use Fragments and treat `large`/`xlarge` devices as tablets. It hadn't occurred to me that manufacturers might deliberately (mis)categorise their 5"-7" devices as `normal` but it makes a lot of sense and hopefully they have done so.